# How to convert std::thread::id to string in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

How to typecast `std::thread::id` to string in C++? I am trying to typecast output generated by  `std::this_thread::get_id()` to a string or char array.

Comment: what do you mean by "convert"? what do you want to do with the "converted" `std::thread::id`?

Comment: @Walter I want to log it for debug purpose

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
auto myid = this_thread::get_id();
stringstream ss;
ss << myid;
string mystring = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 19):

Actually `std::thread::id` is *printable* using `ostream` (see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id/operator_ltlt)).

So you can do this:

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream ss;

ss << std::this_thread::get_id();

std::string idstr = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 6):

You may "convert" it to a small integer number useful for easy identification by humans:

```
std::size_t index(const std::thread::id id)
{
    static std::size_t nextindex = 0;
    static std::mutex my_mutex;
    static std::unordered_map<std::thread::id, std::size_t> ids;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex);
    auto iter = ids.find(id);
    if(iter == ids.end())
        return ids[id] = nextindex++;
    return iter->second
}
```

Comment: Not a strict answer to the question, but a very useful answer nonetheless!

Comment: What the purpose of these code? Index does not show "real" thread sequence number. It almost the same "useless text" but useless number.

Comment: It provides a unique id to the thread. Your "real thread sequence number" is less unique, since it is implementation dependent -- while most implementations use pthreads, that's not guaranteed, nor is the existence of a "real thread sequence number".

Comment: This is impressive, horrifying, and useful all at once.