# How to know how many resource thread use?

Tags: c++, linux

I have a source code that is using some threads.

I want to see how many percent cpu and percent memory are used each threads.

So I used "htop" command. (I am using ubuntu.)

There are "PID" columns which is Process/thread ID.

I googled how to get thread id.

1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id/hash
2. [How to convert std::thread::id to string in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255137/how-to-convert-stdthreadid-to-string-in-c)

But, somehow the thread ids I got from source code are not matched with PID values, one of htop command's output.

Any better idea or help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

PID is **P**rocess ID. Run `top -H`

[man 1 top](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html)

```
-H  :Threads-mode operation
     Instructs top to display individual threads.  Without this
     command-line option a summation of all threads in each
     process is shown.  Later this can be changed with the `H'
     interactive command
```

Comment: I used it. but seems no different.

Comment: What does "no difference" mean? `top -H` must show completely different data.

Comment: "no difference" means still no match PID with source code output. Thread-mode seems expand and collapse toggle key, process id only or process id with that's thread ids but, any PID no match with source code output that I got from upper links 1, 2.

Comment: I doubt that is data displaying format problem?

Comment: `std::thread::id` is not a real thread id. *This class is designed for use as key in associative containers, both ordered and unordered.* This can be a hash of a real thread id.

Comment: How can I get a real thread id from the class std::thread::id ??

Comment: You can do it only in a thread function.

Comment: You can look at all threads with `top -H -pPID` with PID of your program.